# How do we create a unique link for SharePoint survey?

Tags: hyperlink, survey-list, unique

I have a survey which where it should be possible to reply more then once but not with the same link.

Is it possible ? How can we create a unique link for SharePoint survey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported as you would have to do some rewrites. Even if user would be accessing from different url you would still record answer in same list so not sure how  you would differentiate results. Check the rewrite supportability from MS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2818415

Comment: Happy to help Adam.